# Add Overlays in beamer \tableofcontents items

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, overlays

I'm writing a presentation in beamer.

I want to show semi-transparent overlays in the table of contents items. I mean, I want to show the current item text in black color and the next ones in gray.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your preamble add `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` to make inactive overlay items transparent. The table of contents can be displayed emphasizing only the "current section" by using the optional parameter:

```
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
```

If you want to uncover the table of contents section-by-section use the `pausesections` option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}

\begin{document}
\frame{\tableofcontents[pausesections]}
\section{One}
\frame{One}
\section{Two}
\frame{Two}
\section{Three}
\frame{Three}
\end{document}
```

Please see [the beamer user guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) for additional options.

Comment: Thanks, that macro lets gray all the items and lets to show the outline in the begining of each section. But what i need is to make transitions in the outline of tableofcontents frame.

Comment: I mean, I want my Outline like in this tutorial http://www.uncg.edu/cmp/reu/presentations/Charles%20Batts%20-%20Beamer%20Tutorial.pdf, where there are transitions between outline items.  I Really appreciate your help @hakaze. Thanks.

Comment: @Herman I updated my solution. Please remember for your next question to make it as comprehensive as possible and to include examples of what you tried and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @hakaze I really appreciate your help, I used \setbeamercovered{dynamic} and \frame{\tableofcontents[pausesections]} and it works. Thanks!!!!