# Beamer ToC Advanced Overlays

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, formatting

I want to have a Table of Contents in my Beamer presentation, but I want it to be laid out in an apparently particular way. For the first section, what I want is an overlay for each section (I currently have 3) with the *n*th section "shown" and the others shaded. At the start of the other sections, I just want to show that section and have the others shaded. Those last ones I can do (I just can't use `\AtBeginSection` since my first section will be different) and looking at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67218/add-overlays-in-beamer-tableofcontents-items) got me halfway to where I want, but I want to be able to make the other sections shaded again. My code present looks something like the following:

```
\documentclass[pdf,usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
    \setbeamercovered{still covered={\opaqueness<1->{20}},again covered={\opaqueness<1->{20}}}
    \begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents[pausesections]
    \end{frame}
    \setbeamercovered{invisible}
    \subsection{Subsection 1a}
     ...
\section{Section 2}
    \begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Subsection 2a}
    ...
\section{Section 3}
    \begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Subsection 3a}
     ...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the appearance of the table of contents with the `sectionstyle` and `subsectionsectionstyle` commands.

In your particular case you can use `\tableofcontents[pausesections]` for the first section (as you did before) and `\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded, subsectionstyle=show/show/shaded]` for the following sections.

The full MWE look like:

```
\documentclass[pdf,usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
    \begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents[pausesections]
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Subsection 1a}

\section{Section 2}
    \begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded, subsectionstyle=show/show/shaded]
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Subsection 2a}

\section{Section 3}
    \begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded, subsectionstyle=show/show/shaded]
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Subsection 3a}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I'm looking for. Using `\tableofcontents[currentsection]` is actually what I want for sections 2 and 3. Basically, I want section 1's table of contents frame to be 3 slides, with only 1 section (and all of its subsections) "shown" per slide, and the others be "shaded," as opposed to what it's doing now, which is that the frame is 3 slides, but each section stays "shown" on all of the succeeding slides.

Comment: @achstishlosh Before I edit my answer, I try to understand what you really want. Because at the moment there is only one subsection in section 1. Thus, I do not see what you mean by "3 slides, with only 1 section (and all of its subsections) "shown" per slide".